# Execute methods which call each other. All in background

Tags: ios, concurrency, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

In My application, I have few methods calling each other to parse XML downloaded feed, I need to make all parsing stuff in the background with `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` as for now it's being executed in the main thread and freezing the whole app.

My App logic is something like the following:

```
-(IBAction) callSync{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APIURL]];

    AFURLConnectionOperation *operation = [[AFURLConnectionOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.completionBlock = ^{
          //1
          [self startParsing:operation.responseString];
    };
    [operation start];
}

//2
-(void)startParsing:(NSString*)str
{
         //some logic
         [self traverseXML:str];//Call traverseXML
}
//3
- (void) traverseXML:(TBXMLElement *)element {
        //Some logic
        [self saveFile:localWS];//CallsaveFile
}
//4
-(void) saveFile : (WorkFile *)_workFile{
        //Some logic
}
```

My question is: Should I subclass an `NSOperation` class for each method, I mean one for `startParsing`, and one for `traverseXML`, etc? or just it's enough to create one `NSOperation` subclass and do all implementation methods inside.

Comment: By the way, I would not have expected the above code sample to block your main thread (it's one of the joys of AFNetworking). Are you saying it does?

Comment: Yes, it's blocking main thread and my app is freezed for a long time until all XML feed is being parsed completely.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You don't need to do any `NSOperation` subclassing. You can if you really want to, but seems entirely unnecessary in this situation. Much easier is if, for example, you had a separate operation queue for the parsing process, you can just do `addOperationWithBlock` or create a `NSBlockOperation` and add that to your parsing queue. For example:

   ```
   [self.parseQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
       [self startParsing:operation.responseString]; // this will call traverseXML and saveFile, so if those are all synchronous, then all three are within this one block
   }];
   ```

   Personally, the only time I'm going through the extra work of subclassing `NSOperation` is when I have to implement my own custom cancellation logic or I'm creating an operation that encompasses some task that, itself, is asynchronous, and I want to control when the operation sets `isFinished`. Or I subclass `NSOperation` when the operation, itself, hits some significant level of complexity that abstracting it to a separate operation class improves code legibility. But nothing you've described so far suggests that you need to do `NSOperation` subclassing. And just using `NSBlockOperation` or, better, just `addOperationWithBlock`, is far simpler that subclassing `NSOperation`.
2. So, setting aside the "subclassing `NSOperation`" question, let's turn to whether you want separate operations for your three methods or not. Given that you're performing these three tasks sequentially, then that initially sounds like a candidate for a single operation. You certainly could create three separate operations, if you wanted, but I don't see any compelling business case for that additional level of complexity.
3. In my mind, the more interesting question is "what operation queues will I create". For that, it's a question of whether you want concurrency (very useful in network operations, for example) and to what degree (e.g. it's good to not issue too many concurrent network requests, namely, sticking max of four or five). And that's only an issue if you're downloading multiple XML files and parsing them. In that scenario, I could imagine that you might have one queue for the network operations, and another for the parsing operations. That way, you could configure your network queue to enjoy some concurrency, but constrain the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` so you don't have too many concurrent network requests. The parsing/saving operations may have different concurrency capabilities (e.g. if you're not instantiating a separate parser object, your parsing might not support concurrency at all). Often it comes down to balancing the performance gains of concurrency with the memory consumption and program complexity required of such concurrency.

Comment: +1 for the great explanation. let's say I will adopt for `NSOperation`, should I put the code of `traverseXML`and `saveFile` in the `NSOperation` subclassed class in a method, and then call it when instantiating this class?

Comment: @Malloc If you use a `NSOperation` subclass, you either have to put the code in your operation class, or you need to pass it a block that it will call. You probably would have the standard `NSOperation` `start` method initiate the parse.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with one `NSOperation`, as the 3 operations you want to do don't actually live by themselves.

Perhaps only saving should be in another class, but I don't think it's a problem to do it on the same operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //parse
    //traverse
    //save

    dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^{

        //update UI
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, I'm not quite sure why your code is blocking the main thread. When I put a breakpoint in my completion block, for example, I can clearly see it's happening on a background thread (#5 in this example):

[image: completion]

Thus, I should be able to do whatever time consuming process I want there without affecting the UX (such as my command to sleep for five seconds, which in my sample project does not freeze the UI).

Just as a point of contrast, if I put a breakpoint in the progress block (which `AFNetworking` dispatches back to the main queue), it is on the main thread, as expected:

[image: progress]

Since that is happening on the main queue, I would have to be very careful about making sure I don't do anything too time consuming there, because that would block the UI.

(BTW, you might have to <kbd>control</kbd>-click on the above images to open them in another tab/window in your browser to see them legibly.)

But, bottom line, it strikes me that the main parsing process, if you're doing that in the completion block, should already run asynchronously. Sure, I might refine it to submit the `AFURLConnectionOperation` to some network queue and add the parse operation to a separate parse operation queue, but it strikes me that this code should already run asynchronously.

I only mention that because it strikes me that you're about to embark on a process of converting this parsing to a background operation, but it seems worthwhile confirming why your code is freezing your app in the first place.

For example, if the parsing process is using some locking mechanism, such as `@synchronized`, to synchronize the parsing (and when you do stuff asynchronously, you have to think long and hard about how you're going to [synchronize it properly](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) to ensure thread safety), simply moving this code to another background operation will not remedy that situation. Likewise, if your parser is dispatching some code to `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, you would have to refactor that, as well.